# Problem detecting an added or edited row Google Apps Scritps Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a problem with my code, I have this code that looks towards a webhook, the purpose of this code is to detect when a row is added or edited, and when that happens, this change is added to another sheet, it detects well the added and edited rows but only when it is done by hand, when the data is pasted or put automatically it does not detect anything, does anyone know why it could be?

```
function onChange(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
var actualSheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
var current_cell = sheet.getActiveCell().getA1Notation()
if(editedCell.getRow() !== 1 && actualSheetName === "Hoja 2"){
var startRow = 1;
var startColumn = 1;
var numRows = 1;
var numColumns = ss.getLastColumn();
var header = ss.getSheetValues(startRow, startColumn, numRows, numColumns);
var changedRow = ss.getSheetValues(editedCell.getRow(), startColumn, numRows, numColumns);
var data = {};

for (var i = 0; i < header[0].length; i++) {
  data["gs"+i] = changedRow[0][i]
}
data['current_cell'] = current_cell;
var options = {
  'method': 'post',
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  'payload': JSON.stringify(data)
};
UrlFetchApp.fetch("my_webhook", options);
}}
```

Thanx!

Comment: Only some api calls like zapier may trigger `onChange()`. Check execution logs and see if it is triggered.

Comment: i use a software like zapier

Comment: Show executions.